# How to use list numbers to create a range to search for in a text file

Tags: python, list, text

I have 2 lists containing numbers that represents line numbers in a text file,

ie.

```
list1 = [ '1' , '9',  '15']
list2 = [ '7' , '12',  '22']
```

I wanted to use these numbers as a range for a string search, I wanted to assign list1 to starting_line and list2 to ending_line but when I try to run it it doesnt accept a list.

```
search_results=[]
for line in lines[starting_line:ending_line]:
            if 'error ' in line and fail_lines < len(list1):
                line = line.rstrip()
                search_results.append(line)
```

My goal is to scan through the list and then run the search so for example

```
for line in lines[1:7]: and then [9:12] , [15:22]
           if 'error ' in line and fail_lines < len(list1):
                    line = line.rstrip()
                    search_results.append(line)
```

What should i change or add in my code right now?

Comment: May I know why you are splitting it up into two lists?

Comment: You could easily use tuples like `[(1, 7), (9, 12), ...] `, but never mind that, what is `lines`? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: ending point is not included in slice, for e.g. line7 is not included in `lines[1:7]`, you need `lines[1:8]` for 7 lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop the two list at the same time using the function `zip`

```
for startLine, endLine in zip(list1, list2):
    print(startLine, endLine) # this will give you (1, 7), (9, 12) and so on
    for line in lines[startLine:endLine]:
        ... # check the keyword in your line here
```

Comment: I tried using the zip but when i tried to run the the for loop
 for line in lines[startLine:endLine]:       it loops multiple times for a single pair of lines eg 1,7

Comment: There is no way it will loop itself multiple times if you implemented it correctly. Can you show your updated code?

Comment: Oh sorry i just forgot to add to initialize the break at the bottom and clear the search results , my bad. Thank you. Also, on my string "error" search it only shows the first hit and only shows one line but it has many line that contain error,  can you see where did I go wrong on the looping statement ?